# How can I create a Form that doesn't get to front or that doesn't get focus, if i active him

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, focus

I want make a Form in Visual Basic, that can't get focus and can't be brought to front from another windows
I have searched a lot but I haven't found anything.
I tried this code, that make for me sense:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Thats Timer, that have Interval to 1
    If Me.Focused = True Then
        Me.Focused = False
    End If
End Sub
```

But I don't have any idea for this.
I have reviewed tons of questions on how to have the window "TopMost" or again with focused everytime, but, i want him have hidden from another Windows, and must not be able to get focus.
Any great idea will be appreciated

Comment: It's relatively *complicated*. Add this information to the question: - The Form should or should not have a Caption (it can or cannot be moved) - The Form should or should not have an icon in the Taskbar (`ShowInTaskbar = true / false`) - The Form should or should not be resizable - The Form should or should not have child Controls other than Buttons - Any other detail you can think of that better describe your use case

Comment: There is already a tons of answer for your question on SO. You should add a [Window Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles), specifically `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` to your window. Also, bad choice of title. You have to be more concise.

Comment: I suggest that you read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?459890). I'm not going to pick out the specifically relevant parts for an answer but the `UnselectableForm` class I created in that thread will basically do what you want. That was for an OSK, so I probably set `TopMost` to `True`, but you can change that if you need it.

Comment: but, i don't wan't have in TopMost, or "ShowInTaskbar", that i know, but i wan't the Form, that will be stayed back, from another windows, so for example, when i run that form, and bunch of another random windowses(like notepad, mspaint etc), and then when i click on that form, then i wan't that the form will stay there, and not go to the front from the another windowses.
P.S. i litteraly do in vb, 3 year's, and all the basic's i know :D, but like this one, i have no clue